# Uninstall VSTO plugin using batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-installer, registry, vsto

I've to uninstall a vsto plugin. I'm using this command in powershell :

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe" \Uninstall file:///C:/Users/username/source/repos/OutlookAddIn3/OutlookAddIn3/publish/OutlookAddIn3.vsto
```

This statement I copied from `UninstallString` in registry of this Add-in. But this gives following error in powershell :

```
At line:1 char:78
+ ... iles\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe" \Uninstall "file:/ ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\Uninstall' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Can someone tell the correct way of using this command?

**Edit 1:**
The cause of error was using `\uninstall` instead of `/uninstall` and as per the suggestion given by @Abraham Zinala, I added `&` before the command to make it run in PowerShell.

```
& "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe" /uninstall file:///C:/Users/username/source/repos/OutlookAddIn3/OutlookAddIn3/publish/OutlookAddIn3.vsto /silent
```

To make it work in using Batch file, just have to remove `&` previous command. The working command in batch file is :

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe" /uninstall file:///C:/Users/username/source/repos/OutlookAddIn3/OutlookAddIn3/publish/OutlookAddIn3.vsto /silent
```

Comment: Batch, or PowerShell? If you're using PowerShell, try it using the *invocation* (*call*) operator: `&`. So, something like: `& "C:\Program Files....."`

Comment: In PowerShell, tried using ```&``` operator. It displays a pop-up with message ```One or more of the command-line operations are not supported```

Comment: Does it work directly from cmd.exe?

Comment: In cmd, it gives ```& was unexpected at this time.``` . But I want to add this statement in batch file and when i run this command with ```&``` in .bat file, nothing happens

Comment: Without the call operator.

Comment: Gives ```One or more of the command-line operations are not supported``` without ```&``` when executed through cmd as well as  batch script